# Trying to query SQL Server 2008 from C#, program seems to hit an endless loop that I can't explain

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sqlcommand

I have a SQL Server database and I'm trying to query it. First I retrieve all names and id's from a table called `Firms`, use that to populate a `ListBox`. When I click a an item in that list box I want to populate another `ListBox` with employees that work for said firm.

I use this query (tested in SQL Server 2008)

```
SELECT
    employee.Name
From
    employee, Firm
WHERE
    Firm.Name = 'Some Firm' AND
    Firm.F_Id = employee.F_Id
```

This is the code for clicking on a list box item:

```
private void Firm_ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String Name = "";
        Int32 F_Id = -1;

        // This for would be useful later on in the program
        // For now it can be ignored
        for (int i = 0; i < Firms.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (Firms.ElementAt(i).GetFirmName().Equals(Firm_ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                Name = Firms.ElementAt(i).GetFirmName();
                F_Id = Firms.ElementAt(i).GetF_Id();
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(Name.ToString() + "\n\t" + F_Id.ToString()); // first message box

        SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT employee.Name From employee, Firm WHERE Firm.Name = " + "'" + 
             Name + "'" + " AND Firm.F_Id = employee.F_Id", SqlConnection);
        SqlDataReader SqlDataReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        MessageBox.Show("Test: " + SqlDataReader.GetString(1)); // second message box

        Employee_ListBox.Items.Clear();
        while (SqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            Employee_ListBox.Items.Add(SqlDataReader.GetString(1));
            MessageBox.Show(SqlDataReader.GetString(1));
        }

        SqlDataReader.Close();
    }
```

First `MessageBox` works, but the second one does not appear. I have no idea what is going on here (not to mention my `ListBox` doesn't get populated).

**EDIT** While debugging I realized that after the read operation, when I attempt to get string I get a horrible exception (I added a try-catch block). I can't even begin to read it, except this

> *Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.*

caught my eye. Yet I can't explain. The connection works, the query I've tested. And even if it didn't return anything ... shouldn't it just print **nothing** and move one ?

**EDIT2** It seems I get an invalid operation exception, not at reader, but at the message box.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?  My guess is the `SqlDataReader.Read()` returns false on the first call.  This probably happens because your query is returning no rows.

Comment: What happens if you execute that query in management studio? does it work ok there?

Comment: What's with giving your variables the exact same name as the class? Got to call Read before GetString().

Comment: Why do you declare the reader object in the style of the class SqlDataReader ? while(reader.Read()) would be more readable.

Comment: @cadrell0 I am trying, I am so new to VS-2012 that I had a hard time finding out how to debug (even though now it seems trivial). I get that it's stuck at read() but why ... the query works (in Sql Server Management Studio), have I miss-spelled something ?

Comment: @Elisa it doesn't matter as far as I'm concerned about reading it, I'm trying to learn and this way I know what is what.

Comment: If the Read() never returns, it's likely locking on something in the database. Also, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader both implement IDisposable, so you should (by default) wrap them in using statements (or otherwise ensure Dispose() gets called even in the face of exceptions).

Comment: Regarding readability, since you have posted this question you obviously expect other people to read it, which makes common/best practice important even to you. Another thing, if you name a variable the same as a class, how can you "know what is what", since you now have the same name for two different things? I think you should at least write it like. e.g. sqlDataReader, though most people will frown even on things that differ only by case (since it's easy to get wrong or confused also by that).

Comment: Do you really have a variable named `SqlConnection` that you are passing to your command object?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn I've renamed it to `sqlConnection`. Any way it presented no errors of any sort and renaming helped in no way

Comment: @EricPetroelje yes, as I've said, it was tested in SSMS and it works there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second message box, you've got this as part of the message:

```
SqlDataReader.GetString(1)
```

Because you haven't yet read anything from the data reader, this command will throw the exception you are seeing.

The command

```
SqlDataReader.Read()
```

needs to appear prior to trying the GetString method. Additionally, you should verify that data was read before executing the GetString method.